# Graphs in beamer

Tags: beamer, nodes, graphs

I have to draw a graph for a presentation I will do in beamer, the nodes of the graph are like in the image below.

[image]

Is it possible to make a graph with this kind of nodes in latex? How could I draw them?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. With use one from among of packages dedicated for drawing. For example `tikz`, pstriks, etc. Please, enlarge your image. Now it is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ EvaMGG,

I don't know if this suits your purpose, but you can try it with `tikz`

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \definecolor{greenfilling}{RGB}{213,232,212}
    \definecolor{greenoutline}{RGB}{143,187,119}
    \definecolor{greyfilling}{RGB}{245,245,245}
    \definecolor{greyoutline}{RGB}{147,147,147} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm] node {$_{0}B_{2}$};
        \draw[fill=greenfilling, draw=greenoutline] (-0.75,0) circle[radius=0.375cm] node[red, font=\tiny] {$\xi$};
        \draw[fill=greyfilling, draw=greyoutline] (0.75,0) circle[radius=0.375cm] node[font=\tiny] {\textcolor{red}{$C:0$}\textcolor{blue}{$/2$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

** EDIT **

for the animation, you can try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{greenfilling}{RGB}{213,232,212}
\definecolor{greenoutline}{RGB}{143,187,119}
\definecolor{greyfilling}{RGB}{245,245,245}
\definecolor{greyoutline}{RGB}{147,147,147} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{test}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[draw=black, circle, minimum size=4cm] at (0,0) {$_{0}B_{2}$}; \pause
                \node[fill=greenfilling, draw=greenoutline, circle,  minimum size=1.5cm] at (-1.5,0) {\textcolor{red}{$\xi$}}; \pause
                \node[fill=greyfilling, draw=greyoutline, circle,  minimum size=1.5cm] at (1.5,0) {\textcolor{red}{$C:0$}\textcolor{blue}{$/2$}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, since I'm using this in graph, is there a way to have a function `node` to which I can call to generate these nodes. To make it more modular...

Comment: Maybe if you added an example of how to draw several of these nodes in a graph I could continue from there....

Comment: @EvaMGG I added the code für the animation. Do you have this in mind?